# Deleting relationships from detached state

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I've been trying to figure out a good solution to this for most of the afternoon, but to no avail.

When I query data using the entity framework (EF), I always use `MergeOption.NoTracking` as I don't want to use database objects for display in my views.  I end up taking the POCO classes generated by the EF and mapping them into view models which have cute little attributes such as required, display name, etc.  When I need to make updates, I end up mapping my view models back into the classes generated by the entity framework and perform the create or update action.

I'm trying to find an easy way to delete a relationship with my objects, but since they are detached, I haven't been able to find a way to do it.  I saw someone recommend attaching and removing the object, but since my object is detached that won't work (it results in an exception with the message `Attach is not a valid operation when the source object associated with this related end is in an added, deleted, or detached state. Objects loaded using the NoTracking merge option are always detached.`).

Here is an example of my current code:

```
    //Find the records that need to be deleted.
    var productVersionsToDelete = (from pv in existingDownloadFile.ProductVersions
                                  where !selectedVersions.Contains(pv.Id)
                                  select pv).ToList();

    foreach (var productVersionToDelete in productVersionsToDelete) {
        existingDownloadFile.ProductVersions.Attach(productVersionToDelete);
        existingDownloadFile.ProductVersions.Remove(productVersionToDelete);
    }
```

Does anyone have recommendations for deleting objects from a detached state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, once attach is called, the whole object graph is attached. Given a `DbContext` called `context`, an example which should work would be the following:

```
// Attach the download file to the context set (this will attach all ProductVersions
context.DownloadFiles.Attach(existingDownloadFile);

//Find the records that need to be deleted.
var productVersionsToDelete = (from pv in existingDownloadFile.ProductVersions
                              where !selectedVersions.Contains(pv.Id)
                              select pv).ToList();

foreach (var productVersionToDelete in productVersionsToDelete)
    existingDownloadFile.ProductVersions.Remove(productVersionToDelete);

context.SaveChanges();
```

This assumes `DownloadFiles` is the name of a property on your `DbContext` which exposes entities which match the type of `existingDownloadFile`.

The exception you were getting is because once you attach a `ProductVersion`, it attaches the related `existingDownloadFile`, which can only be attached once.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that did the trick.  One question though.  The `existingDownloadFile` in my case wasn't attached.  All of my objects are in a detached state.  Was the error occurring simply because the top object in the relationship chain needs to be attached?  I'm still not sure I've wrapped my head around *why* the error was happening.

Comment: I believe when you were attaching the first `productVersionToDelete`, it had a reference back to `existingDownloadFile`, which would have caused it to be attached too. The next time `attach` was called it was attempting to attach `existingDownloadFile` again, but it was attached the first time, so the error occurred.